Symfony OneToMany Associations sorted by name of OneToOne other entity
In OneToMany Symfony association, it's easy to choose the way to sort.
For instance, if I have a shop with several products that I want to sort by name I can do :
#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'shop', targetEntity: Product::class)]
#[ORM\OrderBy(["name" => "ASC"])]
private $products;

However if for some reason the name is not in "Product" entity but let's say in "item" entity which have a OneToOne relation with "Product".
My goal would be to make something like that (but working) :
#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'shop', targetEntity: Product::class)]
#[ORM\OrderBy(["item.name" => "ASC"])]
private $products;

Is there a way ?
